# Python socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host but ping works

Tags: python, sockets, routes

I am trying to connect using TCP. In the client side I have the following code

```
import socket
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

server_addres = ('172.16.1.52',3201)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(server_addres)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print "received data:", data
```

I run it using:

```
sudo python myProgram.py
```

This error appears

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

However if i run:

```
sudo ping 172.16.1.52
```

The pings work properly. I need to run ping as sudo because running it without sudo gives `ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Check any firewalls. Also check the route using [\[die.net\]: `traceroute`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It ended up being a routing policy of a radio interface. It didn't allow TCP packets. The rule was set by the IT deparment and could not be changed.

I reached this conclusion after sendind TCP packets to other hosts using another interface (i.e. my code worked)

I made sure there was a route. I manually set the routing table for the specific IP and made sure the input policy from the remote host was set to accept TCP packets.

Comment: what would be the reason if the error is raised sometimes when there is high load?